# Accuracy in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Here is slightly modified code that I found [here](https://github.com/kavgan/nlp-in-practice/blob/master/text-classification/notebooks/Text%20Classification%20with%20Logistic%20Regression.ipynb)...

I am using the same logic as the original author and still not getting good accuracy. The Mean Reciprocal Rank is close (mine: 52.79, example: 48.04)

```
cv = CountVectorizer(binary=True, max_df=0.95)
feature_set = cv.fit_transform(df["short_description"])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    feature_set, df["category"].values, random_state=2000)

scikit_log_reg = LogisticRegression(
    verbose=1, solver="liblinear", random_state=0, C=5, penalty="l2", max_iter=1000)

model = scikit_log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

target = to_categorical(y_test)
y_pred = model.predict_proba(X_test)
label_ranking_average_precision_score(target, y_pred)
>> 0.5279108613021547

model.score(X_test, y_test)
>> 0.38620071684587814
```

But the accuracy of notebook sample (59.80) does not match with my code (38.62)

Is the following function used in the sample notebook correctly returning accuracy?

```
def compute_accuracy(eval_items:list):
    correct=0
    total=0

    for item in eval_items:
        true_pred=item[0]
        machine_pred=set(item[1])

        for cat in true_pred:
            if cat in machine_pred:
                correct+=1
                break


    accuracy=correct/float(len(eval_items))
    return accuracy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notebook code is checking whether the actual category is in the top 3 returned from the model:

```
def get_top_k_predictions(model, X_test, k):
    probs = model.predict_proba(X_test)
    best_n = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[:, -k:]
    preds=[[model.classes_[predicted_cat] for predicted_cat in prediction] for prediction in best_n] 
    preds=[item[::-1] for item in preds]
    return preds
```

If you replace the evaluation part of your code with the below, you'll see that your model returns a top-3 accuracy of 0.5980 as well:

```
...    

model = scikit_log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

top_preds = get_top_k_predictions(model, X_test, 3)
pred_pairs = list(zip([[v] for v in y_test], top_preds))
print(compute_accuracy(pred_pairs))

# below is a simpler & more Pythonic version of compute_accuracy
print(np.mean([actual in pred for actual, pred in zip(y_test, top_preds)]))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this: "The notebook code is checking whether the actual category is in the top 3". Is this a standard practice? Are there any use cases when it is OK to consider a match if the test result appear in top 3? Or it is just a tutorial?

Comment: It's not an uncommon metric for multi-class classification like this one (see e.g., one of the first big neural net image recognition papers where they look at top-1 and top-5 accuracy of their classifier: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/imagenet.pdf). For binary classifiers, you more often see metrics like ROC curves and precision-recall since they give a much richer view vs. straight model accuracy at some fixed cutoff.